# Currently online visitors logic in PHP

Tags: php, database, session, caching, optimization

It could be a really easy thing to do but I am getting pretty confused by it.

Basicly, I want to get the amount of people currently browsing my website. The problem is, I can't count sessions. Many of them are created for different purposes. (e.g $_SESSION['age'] for the users who logged in.)

Also, there are "logged_in" and "not_logged_in" people.

In short, how can I count the users in my website **in the most professional way?**

Ps. Please note that I will run the function every 1-5 minutes, get the amount, store it to be used as cache. After 5 minutes, cache will be replaced again, and so on. Hence, db connections will be a possibility if you think that would be the most professional way.

Comment: http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/9.html For example

Answer (score 2):

One of the issues at hand is, your PHP doesn't know when your user closes the browser.

I've done something similar with a combination of a "last_used"-field in the user database (timestamp/datetime) and a "heartbeat"-function (jscript), which regularly sends an "I'm still alive"-command to the server (every x seconds), where then this last_used-field is updated. It ain't a high traffic site, but it does the job very reliable.

Then just count the amount of users which a very current heartbeat in the database:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM your_user_table 
WHERE last_used > TIMESTAMPADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 SECOND)
```

You don't need a user table for this, you can use a session table, too. Such a mechanism can then be used for other features, too, like giving the users new messages on the fly and similar.

Comment: I believe I'll be connecting to a PHP page, get results, clean current DIV and replace DIV with the info given by PHP page. How can I make a heartbeat function like this JS?

Comment: Well, that depends on what techniques you want to use. This is one way to deal with the question you've asked which is quite often used. If your app is JScript-free, then you'll eventually run in to the issues described by me. If you use a widespread JScript-library (JQuery, Mootools or such), then there are many examples out there how to do this.